# Access view of other layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have one MainActivity and two fragments namely Input.java and Output.java. I want to access the textview located at output_layout in Input fragment (More precisely, if I click on the button in input_layout, the textview of output_layout should change). How can i do this? I am calling these input_layout and out_put layout dynamically in main_activity.

As I am beginner, pardon my ignorance. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to move [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=communication%20between%20fragments%20in%20android).

Comment: @AlexK yes. communicate is only referred to send data from one to other fragement?

Comment: @ajay : Don't adopt a philosophy of Fragment to Fragment communication. A `Fragment` should be modular, self-contained and reusable. At any given time a `Fragment` should never 'know' about the existance of any other `Fragment`. All communication from one `Fragment` to another should be done through the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use interfaces. 
For example.

```
 public interface OnOutputFragmentTextChanger {
        public void onChangeText(String what);
    }
```

In onAttach method of Input.class do next:

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnOutputFragmentTextChanger) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnOutputFragmentTextChanger");
        }
    }
```

And in yours OnClickListener call mCallback.onChangeText("Foooo");

Next in Output class create method

```
public void updateInputView(String what)
{
    mTextView.setText(what);
}
```

Next implement OnOutputFragmentTextChanger in Activity and Override method onChangeText(String what):

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnOutputFragmentTextChanger
    {
    //do somwthing 

        @Override
        public void onChangeText(String what)
        {
             InputFragment inputfragment = (InputFragment)
             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment); // or try                findFragmentByTag

             if (inputfragment != null) 
               {
                     inputfragment.updateInputView("some string");
               }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can  declare the TextView in the input layout as public static in the corresponding fragment and directly access it in other fragment where you want to set the value onclick of the button

Comment: suppose i have declared textview as public static in Output.java , then i can access ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.output_textview)).setTexe("answer"). Right??

Comment: Don't declare `public static` variables or methods in a `Fragment` or in an `Activity`. These are two classes where `public static` can cause problems.

Comment: @Squonk then what should i do?

Comment: @ajay : When something happens in a `Fragment` it should 'tell' the `Activity`. It is then the responsibility of the `Activity` to communicate with any other `Fragments`. The `Activity` *ALWAYS* 'knows' how many `Fragments` it is hosting but no `Fragment` should 'know' of the existence of any other. Think of it like this - a tablet may have a multi-pane layout with multiple `Fragments` but on a phone the layout is single pane / single `Fragment` - in the latter case it would be impossible to communicate with another `Fragment` so communicate with the `Activity` and it can handle it.

Comment: @Squonk thanks. So far I was so confused about Fragment and Activity. You made it more clear